# '-[UITableViewController setRootController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I have an app which runs nice on my iPhone 5c, and in the simulator iPhone Retina 3,5 inches and 4 inches, but when I run it in the simulator foe iPhone Retina 4-inch 64-bit.

The app immediately crashes at start with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setRootController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ba1e30'

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first suggestion would be to examine the exception trace and figure out where your exception is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if you're calling "`initWithRootViewController:`" in your code, make sure you're doing that on a "`UINavigationController`" object and not your "`UITableViewController`" object.

Your "`UITableViewController`" object is the view controller you pass in (as a parameter) to the "`initWithRootViewController:`" method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but my the view controller which is marked as the root view controller in my storyboard is Stefano Antonelli's SASlideMenuRootViewController from his SASlideMenu https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu. This is not a UITableViewController, just a normal UIViewController...

Comment: Why not set an Xcode breakpoint on the "`setRootController:`" symbol and see what line of code Xcode stops at?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the debugger in XCode (I come from Android). How do I set the breakpoint?

Comment: [Here is how Apple says to do it in Xcode](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Frecipes%2Fxcode_help-breakpoint_navigator%2Farticles%2Fadding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html&ei=LJv3UtSNL86FogTmkYLIAg&usg=AFQjCNGzLRPPH0ic2-r1lcZMwa0gYy0C9A&sig2=g6fFIUoEmvhFCnXR981N-w).

Comment: I think, I have found some hints in what is going wrong: At the beginning of the debug output: `2014-02-09 16:42:26.275 MedSafeStatic[9453:70b] Unknown class ExampleStaticMenuViewController in Interface Builder file.
2014-02-09 16:42:26.281 MedSafeStatic[9453:70b] -[UITableViewController setRootController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8db1110
2014-02-09 16:42:26.284 MedSafeStatic[9453:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setRootController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8db1110'`

Comment: To elaborate further: I build my app around the SASlideMenu component. So, I refactored some of the class names, including the ExampleStaticMenuViewController. So I added the ExampleStaticMenuViewController from SASlideMenu sources. What happens now in the Retina 4inch-64-bit simulator, is that the app starts displaying the SASlideMenu Example app. However when I run it on my device or the other simulators, then my app displays. So I believe that some linking / compiling for 64-bit doesn't work correctly, but I don't have a clue where to look...

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why, but it worked again after opening older versions of the same project in XCode, and then running the current version again......???